# How to hold greater values for (2^(n-1) mod 1 =1) in JAVA

Tags: java, int, biginteger

I`m trying to solve the "prime generator" in SPOJ, finding prime using the 2^(n-1)%n==1, but it becomes greater for integer, long at some point, therefore I tried BigInteger, and even now it is not showing output.

I have already tried various other techniques, but they quite plainly exceed the time limit, wanted to try something else except SOE algorithm.

```java
import java.io. * ;
import java.math. * ;
import java.util. * ;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System. in );
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            BigInteger a = in.nextBigInteger();
            BigInteger b = in.nextBigInteger();
            for (BigInteger j = a; j.compareTo(b) < -1; j.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
                BigInteger n = j;
                BigInteger r = new BigInteger("2");
                int wow = n.intValue();
                BigInteger y = r.pow(wow - 1);
                System.out.println(y);
                if ((y.mod(n)).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0)
                    System.out.println(j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Does not show any output now.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a tutorial site or help/discussion forum***.  Sorry, but _"not showing output"_ is insufficient description of the problem.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: `j.add(BigInteger.ONE)` will not change anything, because `BigInteger` is immutable. Change it to `j = j.add(BigInteger.ONE)`.

Comment: If the program is not terminating, I suspect you've provided large enough values that your algorithm is taking a long (a very long) time to end.  Please describe more clearly what you mean by "not showing output".

Comment: Why is your `n` loop (well, `j` loop) using `BigInteger`, when you call `intValue()` on it anyway? Make the loop an `int` loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you don't increment `j`.

```
for (BigInteger j = a; j.compareTo(b)<-1; 
                 j.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
```

`j.add(...)` won't change `j`, instead it returns a new `BigInteger`.

To fix your code, just assign the result of `j.add(BigInteger.ONE)` to `j`:

```
for (BigInteger j = a; j.compareTo(b)<-1; 
                 j = j.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
```

---

Bottom line: Please try to debug your code before posting it on StackOverflow.
Use an IDE of your choice.
This kind of errors happen, but they are easily cached if you debug your code and just mindlessly step through the program until you wonder why it did not advance yet.